# How to exclude text between boundaries?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand why my example regex does not work the way I'd like to:

```
test-text: Filename: test myFile 123 .txt
pattern: (?<=Filename:.*?myFile)(.*?)(?=.txt)
Expected Result: 123
```

I know lookahead/behind is not ideal here, but it's just for learning purpose trying to understand.

So why does `.*?myFile` not work? If I remove it, the pattern matches `test myFile 123`. But I want to look for `Filename:`, then exclude everything up to `myFile`, and take everything after and bewteen the last `.txt` statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: Depending on regex flavour, variable-length lookbehinds might not be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the complexities of regex matching, a variable-length lookbehind pattern is not supported.  You should get an error message to that effect.  This is simply a limitation of Perl's regex engine.

There is a somewhat similar feature which allows this: `\K` discards everything to the left from the final match. So this pattern will probably work as you expect it to:

```
/Filename:.*?myFile\K(.*?)(?=.txt)/
```

It is not the same as a true lookbehind, however, in that it doesn't allow overlapping matches.

Incidentally, this is now the third similar question you have posted.  Based on the information you have given, the correct answer is still "don't use look-arounds for this".  If there is a reason you want to use them, you should explain that so we can give better help.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it would still leave leading and trailing spaces. You might also want to include those. `Filename:.*?myFile\s*\K.*?(?=\s*.txt)`

Comment: @AshwinMukhija, yes that is true but this is more of a technical question than an actual regex matching problem.

Comment: That is true, but still useful to include the completely correct pattern. :)

Comment: This was very useful in my case!

Answer (score 1):

Lookbehind assertion must have **fixed length**. but your `.*?myFile` is not.

depends on the language you are using, you could:

`"(?<=Filename:)(.*?myFile\s*)([^\s]*?)(?=\s*.txt)"` and get `group(2)` if you love lookbehind and lookahead.

or

`"Filename:.*?myFile\s*([^\s]*)\s*\.txt"` and get `group(1)`

Comment: Variable length lookbehind is allowed in Perl 6 and .NET

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```
/myFile(.*?)\.txt$/
```

Just capture the group if that's all you're interested in. No need for look-arounds IMO.

Edit: As to what's wrong with yours: Probably your regex engine doesn't support variable length look-arounds.

Comment: While that may be correct, I think the question was about what specifically is wrong with his regular expression. Why doesn't the non-greed operator in the lookahead work?

Comment: (?:Filename:.*?myFile)(.*?)(?:.txt)  non-capturing group ?: not ?=